# Are there terms in German for different skull shapes?

Tags: translation, single-word-request, phrase-request

In English, the term "squarehead" used to refer to Germans and Scandiavians (1), due to their supposedly unusual cranial features (2, 3)

Does the German language have words for the stereotypically British, the stereotypically German (as shown) or other skull shapes?

Sources:

(1) https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squarehead

(2) https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=squarehead (I realize that urbandictionary is not a great source, but it has the only explanation of the etymology of the slur that I could find)

(3) https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-comparison-of-british-german-skull-shapes-ww1-56691744.html (I do not know if this was an actual propaganda poster during WWI, but this is what they claim)

Comment: Please replace "supposedly" with "purportedly". The contents of the poster is just racist bullshit. Otherwise, your question is valid.

Comment: @tofro Is there really any difference between "supposedly" and "purportedly"?

Comment: @sgf yes, of course

Comment: @tofro "supposedly" is appropriate though: from M-W: **"according to what is or was said, claimed, or believed by some"**. You might be thinking of "suppos**ably**", which means "capable of being supposed". Language aside, typical skull shapes do vary by geography. There's nothing racist about it.

Comment: geography only shapes heads, if hit on hard enough. At best, climate might play a role, but mostly genetics, that isn't strictly regionally bound, so you have to be careful not to sound borderline offensive. There are outdated racist slurs pertaining to head shape, indeed.

Comment: @vectory You've misunderstood my statement. I did not write that geography directly CAUSES anything (perhaps indirectly, it does, via adaptation). Only that the typical skull shape varies depending on the location.

Comment: @vectory https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/geography 1.2 "a geographical area; a region"

Comment: imho *depend* is an even stronger word than *caused by*. You might mean *correlation*, but I'm pretty much ignorant about that, and any such correlation might be exceptional. German heads do not differ, on average, typically, or at all. Sure, there might be an anthropologic tangent, but I doubt a bone scholar could identify birthplace from head forms, in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Please don't downvote this answer, merely because you don't like the words it asks for and the associations it evokes in you. This is a site for discussing the German language in a factual manner.

Comment: I do not like this question because the Nazis classified human beings via their *Kopfform* (= skull shape). Look at [this](https://www.zukunft-braucht-erinnerung.de/der-antisemitische-stereotyp/) where you can see that the intention was to distiguish between the "Aryan master race" and "inferior races".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Common terms in popular everyday communication refering to skull shapes are

- Quadratschädel
- Eierkopf
- Flachschädel

As a bonus, here are words used for *head* in general, without special reference to its shape

- Rübe
- Birne
- Kürbis
- Melle
- Deetz
- Dach (eins aufs Dach kriegen)
- Nuss
- Lampe
- Omme

---

(I open this as a community wiki so that others can add terms)

Comment: Famously, former German chancellor Helmut Kohl was sometimes called Birne: ["Birne muß Kanzler bleiben"](https://www.titanic-magazin.de/heft/klassik/1982/november/).

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt  Actually he was practically exclusively called Birne (not by his party members, but pretty much by the rest of the republic). This referred both to his skull and body shape.

Comment: Notably the shape-related terms are typically used only metaphorically (and pejoratively), as in "Quadratschädel" = stubborn person, *Eierkopf* = nerdy scientist, *Flachschädel* = stupid person - no matter what physical shape the person really perhaps has

Answer (score 5):

Craniology is junk science, but I understand you are aware of that. There are nevertheless some typical expressions in German used to describe people's temperament by skull or head terms:

> Er probiert es einfach nochmal? Ja. Er ist eben ein **Dickschädel**.

*He's just trying it again? Yes. Gee, he's a **pig-head**.*

> Die **Betonköpfe** aus Moskau sagen zu allem "Nein."

*The Moscow **pig-heads** are responding "Nyet!" to anything.*

Then, there's the **Pattkopp** ("Pattkopf"), which is literally a deer which cannot grow antlers (due to some illness or old age). It's used to insult clueless people.

**Klapskopf** in contrary is someone who got slapped in the face one time to often and indulges into useless activities and foolishness.

But the most used term is probably **kopflos**, as in

> Die Hintermannschaft agierte völlig **kopflos**.

*The defense acted completely **clueless**.*

Comment: Als Niederländer werde ich auch schon mal Käskopf genannt. Und da gibt es noch den Pappkopp. <g>

Comment: craniology ≠ craniometry

Answer (score 1):

*square* has a metaphorical meaning (hip to be square, don't be a square, fair and square, square on point) and might relate here to the rigid rule thinking stereotypically attributed to Germany (or Prussia), e.g. punctuality. Ironicallly Ger. *Querkopf* means quite the opposite.

*quer* "diagonal, transverse" has a relation to En. *queer*. In *Querdenker* "lateral thinker, alternative thinker, opposition*" has a rather positive connotation, in comparison.