# Slang words for "head" in German and their usage?

Tags: slang

In English we have noggin, melon, bean, coconut, knocker, cantaloupe, egg... and those are just the first ones that come to mind. In German all I know of is "Birne".

What are some other common slang words for "head"? Is their usage regional or specific to a particular situation?

Comment: Off the cuff? Grind, Meggl, Deez, Riabl,... and that’s just *one* dialect.

Comment: Look at the synonyms listed [here](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kopf)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a) based on a misconception (there _are_ plenty of slang words) and b) asking “why” a language is one way or another isn’t helpful.

Comment: Nischl nicht zu vergessen

Comment: This question could well have been used to open a community wiki for collecting such terms. I suppose we would have found 50 at least.

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/52045/are-there-terms-in-german-for-different-skull-shapes/52047

Answer (score 3):

## Slang words for "head" in German:

- Rübe

  - Ribble [bes. südwestd.]
- Birne
- Kürbis
- Melle
- Deetz
- Dach (eins aufs Dach kriegen)
- Nuss
- Lampe
- Omme(l)
- Grind [schweizerisch]
- Däz [bes. schwäb.]
- Meckel [bes. schwäb.]
- Nischl [bes. mitteld.]
- Schädel, Dickschädel, Quadratschädel
- Oberstübchen

---

Thanks to Iris for the [link to an initial list](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/52047/22899) and to Christian Geiselmann for suggesting to open a community wiki.

Comment: I'm not sure whether *Dach* really belongs on that list: As far as I know, it is only a synonym for head when used in the given phrase. I'm not aware of any other context where *Dach* would be understood as *Kopf*. BTW: The same phrase & meaning is also used with *Glocke* or *Zwölf*.

Comment: Die Liste sieht recht vollständig aus. Nur das *Oberstübchen* vermisse ich.

Comment: @Ralph Ist ergänzt

Comment: Da fehlt noch was aus dem norddeutschen/plattdeutschen Raum: "Dötz" ("Nimm ma' dein'n Dötz aus'm Bild!") und auch der "Kopp" ("Mach dir da mal kein' Kopp drum!", oder "Da packst dir doch an'n Kopp!")

Answer (score 1):

In austria there are some additional slang words for head:

- Batterie
- Marün (Marille/Aprikose)
- Deckel (Auf den Deckel bekommen)

There may be more but I can not think of more right now.